# Posting Data with JQuery

Tags: jquery, post

I'm hoping for a little help - Whatever I try I cannot get jQuery to use the post method.
When I look at the request via Charles it is always using the GET method.
The code:

```
   $.post(serviceBaseURL+"get_latest_result_for_location/?jsoncallback=?",{'locationID':locationID}, function(data)
        {

    if(data["status"]=="ok")
    {
        var latestResult = resultToArray(data)[0];
        callback(latestResult);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("server connection failed");
    }

        }, "json");
```

As the server can not get the post data for the request it responds with.

> jQuery152027819979432710484_1301989144102({"status":"fail","message":"Please provide a location ID"});
>
> I am using the latest version of JQuery @http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't solve this so am just checking for GET in my service - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(serviceBaseURL+"get_latest_result_for_location/?jsoncallback=?",{'locationID':locationID}, function(data)
```

It looks like you aren't speifying a location id, why is jsoncallback a ?
and specify locationid in the same way, so:

```
'?jsoncallback=?&locationID=' + locationID
```